# Defining array index in a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, indexing, selector

I have several tables in my HTML markup which don't have any attributes and I'm wondering: is it possible to define a jQuery selector which directly picks eg. the third table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Tim's answer, there's a [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) version you can use inside a selector as well, for example:

```
$("#myContainer table:eq(2) tr")
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah you can use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) from jquery

`$('table').eq(2).css('background-color', 'red');` for example this gets the third table (zero-based counting, jquery starts counting with zero therefor eq(2)) and give it a red background color.